# How to label individual genes of a plot_numerical ( ) using the package "annotatr" in R?

Tags: r, annotations, genome

I would like to know how to label the individual gene names of numerical plot generated from `anotatr`. Please consider the following example from the user guide. Thanks in advance.

In Vignettes from package 'annotatr',
regarding the example given in 4.5.3 Plotting Numerical Data Over Regions,
in Figure 6: Methylation Rates in Regions Over DM Status in Group 0 vs Group 1

https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/annotatr/inst/doc/annotatr-vignette.html

```
dm_vs_regions_name = plot_numerical(
annotated_regions = dm_annotated,
x = 'mu0',
y = 'mu1',
facet = 'annot.type',
facet_order = c('hg19_genes_1to5kb','hg19_genes_promoters',
'hg19_genes_5UTRs','hg19_genes_3UTRs', 'hg19_custom_ezh2',
'hg19_genes_intergenic', 'hg19_cpg_islands', 'hg19_cpg_shores'),
plot_title = 'Region Methylation: Group 0 vs Group 1',
x_label = 'Group 0',
y_label = 'Group 1')
print(dm_vs_regions_name)
```

[image: Plot_numerical]

I want to label the individual dots as per individual genes names (annot.symbol).

[image: GeneNames from Userguide Example 4.2]